# User Interface Designing Tool for WPF using Powerbuilder

Tags: user-interface, powerbuilder

Can anyone suggest me any tool for designing user interface for WPF that can be used in Powerbuilder.

Before this I found a  few tools such https://mui.codeplex.com/ and http://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro but I got problem to use those in my Powerbuilder.net. I don't know either something I missing when try to using them or those tools really not support Powerbuilder.I want to design interface like window 8, so I need tool that can give interactive design. Thanks

Sorry for my bad English T.T

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make it work for you to show by example but I didn't have time to get it done. This should work fine.

First, make sure you add all the references (dll's) needed. In Visual Studio "NuGet" adds all the required references. I believe you need MahApps.Metro.dll, GreyscaleEffect.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll at a minimum. Add them to References in your Solution Explorer.

Then in windows you need to add namespaces depending on what features you want to use, and just like in visual studio you can use the namespace "name" as prefix to use the features of the MahApps assemblies.

PowerBuilder WPF uses the Visual Studio Isolated Shell so it basically works pretty much the same.

hope this helps.
Rich